# iOS Distribution Certification Transfer

Tags: ios, xcode7

My company has a Apple Developer Id, and I have acquired a distribution certification to release Ad Hoc version app for testing. However, now owing to my leaving, they need me to transfer the company Developer id and the certification to other computers.
I export the p12 file of the Distribution Certification and ruined it on other Mac.
On one computer, everything went well, while it did not work on another one. I have tried to download the WRDCA and run it, yet the solution did not figure out the problem.
In addition, I found that on the computer, there is no the certification of Apple Application Integration Certification Authority. Is this the reason why the p12 file did not work on the Mac? If not, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: May I know how is it not working? Receiving error? When it happen? Any details can be provided? Do you export the cert with the private key?

Comment: Originally, after I import the p12 file on another Mac, the status of certification should be "This certification is valid", while in my colleague's Mac, it is still like the authority of certification is not valid, the red one. And, I can not use the certification and its profiles to export the app to a ipa. During building, it noticed me to reset the certification, which I do not want.

Comment: By the way, should I export the cer file as well? Yet, as I said, I tried on two Mac, and the p12 file worked on another Mac, without import the cer file. Only import the p12 file. Also, I found that, on that Mac(not worked one), I did not see the certification of Apple Application Integration  Certification Authority. Does it matter?

Comment: Does the distribution cert includes the private key? if not, you have to export with the private key as well, select both the cert and private key under it and right click export. If theres only Distribution cert but no private key, it won't work, can you see any other difference between that two work and non work mac? Which apple account is using in each of the mac? Is it the same apple ac?

Comment: Apple Application Integration Certification Authority should be there, try to download it in here https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I solve the problem finally. However, all what happened is just because of my careless checking of the invalid AWDRCA on my Mac system. Thanks again and apologise of perhaps wasting your time on my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, I carelessly to ensure to delete all the AWDRCA in my keychain.

If any one else finds that the certification is in the situation of "This certificate was signed by an unknown authority" with the AWDRCA installed in you system, please check whether there is any other AWDRCA in the "System" keychain category which is invalid or overtime. Delete them either if there are. And then your other CA might be valid as well.

In addition, for the certification of Apple Application Integration Certification Authority, it might be less likely, if possible, to influence you CA because the direct signer of the certification is AWDRCA. However, if you doubt about this, you could just download the AAICA at the following address.

[Apple Original PKI Website](https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/)

[A screen print of the website Apple PKI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilj2B.jpg)

There are three kind of AAICA which depends on you. I just use the first one.

Finally, thanks Gary Lip for the patient description. My carelessness might mislead his/her thought of solving my problem.